# Core Data confusion: fetch without tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have completed and reproduced Core Data tutorials using a tableview to display contents. However, I want to access an Entity through a fetch on a view without a tableview. I used the following fetch code, but the count returned is always 0. The data exists when the database is opened using SQLite tools.

```
    NSManagedObject *entryObj;
XYZDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Quote" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; 
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];  
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];   

[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[request setEntity: entity]; 

NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

if (results == nil) {
    NSLog(@"No results found");
    entryObj = nil;
}else {
    NSLog(@"results %d", [results count]);
}

[request release];
[sortDescriptors release];
```

count returned is always 0; it should be 5.

Can anyone point me to a reference or tutorial regarding creating a controller not to be used with a tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, everything looks fine (except I'm a little worried about using 'id' as an attribute name, since it's a keyword in Objective-C).  Try removing the sort descriptor and see if that changes anything.  Also, add an error check.  Perhaps something is happening that that can tell you.  And I assume "Quote" is the right name for the entity.  If none of that helps, I don't think the problem is in the fetch request.

For what it's worth, here's how I would write it:

```
XYZDelegate * appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext * context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Quote" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[sortDescriptor release];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Quote" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSError * error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
[request release];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}

if (results == nil) {
    NSLog(@"No results found");
    entryObj = nil;
}
else {
    NSLog(@"results %d", [results count]);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestions. The error printed out is the name of the class the code is executing in. When doing the same without the sort descriptor, I get a "bad address" error. The results, regardless of what I try return "count: 0". I am wondering if I need an additional method to implement coredata in this case. Please note, I am only reading, not trying to add/delete/update.

Comment: I tried your code, the results were the same (result: 0). Is this all I need to access the "Quote" entity or is their something missing?

Comment: Finally fixed it. Simulator created another folder, with an additonal sqlite database. Switching DBs fixed it. Code was correct after all. Thanks for the help.